# How to fetch the value of checkbox of the triggered button only in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
<tr>
    <td>Category 1</td>
    <td class="data">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name="items[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Item 1
                <input name="items[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Item 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Category 2</td>
    <td class="data">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name="items[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Item 1
                <input name="items[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Item 2
            </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The table is dynamically created with jquery. So, what I want is when I click one of the save button, I want to fetch the checked data from the checkbox of that  only consisting that clicked button, not from the other checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this, i am using this code to display values but you can use it in for save....**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
        var chkvalue = [];
        $.each($("input[name='items']:checked"), function(){            
            chkvalue.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("My chkvalues are: " + chkvalue.join(", "));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use each function of Jquery to get all the checked boxes corresponding to the save button like below

```
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {

    $(this).closest("tr").find(".data [type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});


})
```

Comment: @skonmai Plz accept this answer and also upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".save", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".data [type=checkbox]:checked");
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yt89fhz7/)**

Comment: If you want to get selected value in array use this http://jsfiddle.net/yt89fhz7/1/

Comment: use static parent instead of document

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$(document).on("click",".save",function(){
  var checkedValues = $(this).closest("tr").find(".data :checked").map(function(){
    return this.value;
  }).get(); //["1","2"] depends on user selection
});
```

In the place of document use the closest static parent of `.save` button.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yt89fhz7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

i think using this you can find the value of your check boxes

```js
$('.save').on('click',function(){    
   $(this).prev().find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `checkid` or `checkclass` for Check box :

```
$('#checkid').val();
$('.checkclass').val();
```

or

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").val();
```

or

```js
  $('#test').click(function() {
    alert("Checkbox state (method 1) = " + $('#test').prop('checked'));
    alert("Checkbox state (method 2) = " + $('#test').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check me: <input id="test" type="checkbox" />
```